# What I'm doing wrong in this type checking?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-redux, react-typescript

I'm having a typescript issue that I need to fix as I'm not a fan of `any`.

I'm receiving this error and I'm tired of trying to fix it, idk how I should proceed atm.
[image]
This error is inside my reducer, which is:

```
const dieselReducer = (state = initialState, action: DieselActionTypes): Diesel => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case GET_DIESEL:
      return getDiesel(state, action);
    case GET_DIESEL_SUCCESS:
      return getDieselSuccess(state, action);
    case GET_DIESEL_FAILURE:
      return getDieselFailure(state, action);
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

This is my `getDieselSuccess` function:

```
const getDieselSuccess = (state: Diesel, action: GetDieselSuccess) => {
  return {
    ...state,
    loading: false,
    diesels: action.payload.map(item => ({
      value: { ...item },
      label: item.descricao,
    })),
  };
};
```

And this is my `types.ts`:

```
export interface ValueProps {
  associated: boolean;
  id: string;
  name: string;
  porto: boolean;
}

export interface DieselProps {
  value: ValueProps;
  label: string;
  descricao: string;
}

export interface Diesel {
  diesels: DieselProps[];
  loading: boolean,
  error: {};
}

export interface GetDieselSuccess {
  type: typeof GET_DIESEL_SUCCESS;
  payload: DieselProps[];
}
```

And to finish, this is how I receive my data from the backend(which is converted as shown in `getDieselSuccess` function:

```
[
  {
    "id": "afdc4808-fc1d-47bf-ee8013b058a4",
    "descricao": "ANP",
    "premissasContratuais": []
  },
  {
    "id": "5c06e835-cdfb-4ae9-e8e9d255dc85",
    "descricao": "ANP Est",
    "premissasContratuais": []
  }
]
```

Sorry for the long topic but can someone please help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `getDieselSuccess` function is supposed to return a `Diesel` object which should contain a `diesels` property which should contain a `descricao` property which is missing.

Your function should therefore be:

```js
const getDieselSuccess = (state: Diesel, action: GetDieselSuccess) => {
  return {
    ...state,
    loading: false,
    diesels: action.payload.map(item => ({
      value: { ...item },
      label: item.descricao,
      descricao: 'YOU-NEED-A-VALUE-HERE' /* Add this prop */
    })),
  };
};
```

or even better (since `action.payload` seems to be of `DieselProps[]` type)

```js
const getDieselSuccess = (state: Diesel, action: GetDieselSuccess) => {
  return {
    ...state,
    loading: false,
    diesels: action.payload,
  };
};
```